# Evaluation of a formal series at a point

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, quotient-spaces, formal-power-series

Let $R$ be a ring. On the ring of polynomials $A[X]$ I can define an evaluation map in $r \in R$ (the morphism that sends $X$ to $r$, extended by linearity and multiplication). This allows to "evaluate" polynomials at $r$. Of course, this cannot be replicated verbatim on arbitrary formal series rings, unless some notion of convergence in the base ring is used.

What puzzles me, though, is the following: for $R[X]$, the evaluation of $f \in R[X]$ at $r$ can also be viewed as the image of $f$ in $R[X] / (X-r)$. Why can't we do the same for $R[[X]]$? In other words, is there an explicit description of $R[[X]] / (X-r)$? If so, is it isomorphic to $R$? If so, is this isomorphism canonical, or is there a canonical embedding of this quotient into some space independent of $r$ , so that in particular one may compare the evaluations at different points (and do algebraic operations on them)?

Comment: For $k$ a field, the element $-r+X \in k[\![t]\!]$ is a unit if (and only if) $r \neq 0$.

Comment: I meant $k[\![X]\!]$, of course.

Comment: In some sense, $k[X]$ is a *global* object ( - a line - ), whereas $k[\![X]\!]$ is supposed to capture *local* information related to a specific point of the global object.

Comment: @DanielGerigk: Yes, I see why. If $r$ is invertible, $(r-x)^{-1} = r \sum \limits _{n=0} ^\infty r^{-n} X^n$, which converges in the $(X)$-adic topology. Out of pure curiosity, do you happen to know what happens when $r$ is not invertible?

Comment: I think that $k[\![X]\!]/X$ is indeed isomorphic to $k$: the kernel of the homomorphism $k[\![X]\!] \rightarrow k$ which sends a power series to its constant term is generated by $X$.

Comment: You may evaluate a power series at a nilpotent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Gerigk has said in the comments, the element $X-r\in k[[X]]$ is invertible for $r\neq 0$. In this case, $k[[X]]/(X-r)=0$ so this version of evaluation is not very useful.

Comment: Yes, I see why. If $r$ is invertible, $(r-x)^{-1} = r \sum \limits _{n=0} ^\infty r^{-n} X^n$, which converges in the $(X)$-adic topology. Out of pure curiosity, do you happen to know what happens when $r$ is not invertible?